# Raspberry PI 3, static ip doesn't work

Tags: static, ip, raspberry-pi3

I want to give my Raspberry PI a static ip address. I only use a network cable. I do not use WLAN. 
My "/etc/network/interfaces" is set to static, with address, netmas, network, broadcast and gateway specified. After a reboot the address stays the same. In my router giving it a default address is disabled. I also executed "sudo mv /var/lib/dhcp /var/lib/dhcp1" and rebooted again, still no result. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Jessie then you need to update the dhcpcd.conf file in /etc/

At the bottom add:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=<your ip address>/24            
static routers=<your router ip>
static domain_name_servers=<your router ip>
```

save, exit, reboot

Comment: how do i get those values?

Comment: @lollerskates You dont get them. You just choose one. For example, 192.168.4.20